# GWT and java mail api: NoSuchProviderException

Tags: gwt

I have to send an email from a gwt project using java mail api. I manage to do it with a normal java application (a Main project, a Junit test, whatever) but it just doesn't work inside an RPC call on GWT (version 1.7.1). 
I think I'm using the proper java libraries as I can send this email outside GWT.
I'm using it in hosted mode, with the Jetty webserver (not using Google AppEngine), and I got this error:

```
Loading META-INF/javamail.providers from jar:file:/C:/documenti/workspaces/javalou/provatesina/war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.2.6.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=gm,className=com.google.appengine.api.mail.stdimpl.GMTransport,vendor=null, version=null
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: Unable to locate provider for protocol: smtp
```

do you have any idea? thanks!!!

Comment: Do you have GAE disabled in the settings of Google's Plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: yes GAE is disabled...
could it be some problems related to permission policy?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I've got the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427681/osgi-gwt-org-apache-commons-mail-emailexception

Comment: it was ages ago... as far as I remember I had some wrong library in the java_path.
sorry for not being more helpful :/

Try with the answer J-16 gave!

Answer (score 1):

To send email in Google App Eng, you must use [their api](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview.html), and REMOVE ALL JAVA MAIL JARs FROM YOUR FILEs.