# OSGi GWT org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException

Tags: email, gwt, osgi, classloader, apache-commons-email

I have an OSGi application which has a command line interface and a GWT interface. I have a separate bundle that is responsible for sending emails. It uses Apache Commons Email.

The email bundle only provides one method for sending email and all of the properties are hard coded at the moment.

When I send the email from the command line, it gets a reference to the bundle and sends off the email with no problem.

When I send the email from the GWT interface, it gets a reference to the bundle and attempts to send the email and then throws the following exception

`org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : mail.interzet.ru:25
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1242)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1267)
    at com.ardor.email.internal.EmailServiceImpl.send(EmailServiceImpl.java:134)
    at com.ardor.email.internal.EmailServiceImpl.sendChangeEmail(EmailServiceImpl.java:66)
    at com.ardor.web.server.CustomerProxyServiceImpl.changeEmail(CustomerProxyServiceImpl.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:973)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:907)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: Unable to locate provider for protocol: smtp
    at javax.mail.Session.getProvider(Session.java:229)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:338)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:368)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:67)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1232)`

How can this be? It is running the same code

`HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();`

```
email.setHostName(SMTP_HOST);
email.setAuthentication(SMTP_USER, SMTP_PASS);

email.setFrom(SMTP_EMAIL, SMTP_NAME);
email.addTo(emailAddress, customerName);
email.setSubject("Subject");
email.setTextMsg("This is my message");
email.setHtmlMsg("This is the HTML");

email.send();
```

Puzzled!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completly sure as to why but It turned out to be a simple class path error. It seems the OSGi bundle had access to javax.mail_1.4.0.jar and the war doesn't have access to it.

I added it to the applications WEB-INF/lib and it now works fine.

It still makes no sense to me why it would need access to it as the OSGi bundle can access it when not being called from GWT

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting this before email sending:

```
Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());   
final Properties props = new Properties();  
props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
props.setProperty("mail.host", SMTP_HOST);  
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");  
props.put("mail.debug", "true");  
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");  
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");  
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {   
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
        return new PasswordAuthentication(SMTP_USER, SMTP_PASS);  
    }  
});
```

Comment: I'm testing on my local machine and my ISP doesn't require authentication for SMTP. Also the damn thing works when I run it at the command line. I think from the stack trace it is some how loading a different class. As the stack trace contains Jetty which is what is hosting the GWT application